# WPF DataGrid RowDetails Visibility binding to a property (with XAML only)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have a DataGrid displaying bunch of Objects. Those objects have a property `IsDetailsExpanded` and I want to bind the DataRows `DetailsVisibility` property to that property.

My first approach works but requires some code-behind (which i would like to get rid of)

i handle the `LoadingRow` event

```
void LoadingRowHandler(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    Binding b = new Binding()
    {
         Source = e.Row.DataContext,
         Path = new PropertyPath("IsExpanded"),
         Converter = (IValueConverter)Resources["BoolToVisi"],
         Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
    };
    e.Row.SetBinding(DataGridRow.DetailsVisibilityProperty, b);
}
```

i think there has to be a way to achieve something similar in XAML but i unfortunately i have not the slightest clue. Any ideas? suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowstyle%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for the `DataGridRow` type, like so:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" Margin="12,12,0,0">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="DetailsVisibility" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisi}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Exactly. That's the xaml way. Only Property should be equal to DetailsVisibility.

Comment: Sometimes i want to abuse this commenting feature and drop some random smileys around. Is it frowned upon: :)))))

Comment: @Yiğit - Not sure, I haven't had any complaints.

Comment: XAML hates me ... i placed that rowStyle but when i change the state of that property nothing seems to happen ... anything else a wpf newbie like me should have done?

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 - Are there any errors in your Output window? You may need to use `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext.IsExpanded, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisi}}`, but I wouldn't think so.

Comment: no exceptions in the output window, just modules beeing loaded, etc ... i tried what you suggested, but no luck ... creating the binding in the eventhandler works fine, so i assume i missed something trivial

Comment: gnahahahahahaa ... *biting in the edge of the table* ... this can't work if the DataGrid has `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"` set ...

Comment: As far as I can tell RowDetailsVisibilityMode overrides this binding regardless of what its value is set to. The binding is ignored.